# Playing AVI Embedded in Powerpoint on a Mac

Tags: macos, video, microsoft-powerpoint, avi, embedded

I had a look at this site for a solution for my particular situation but was unable to find any that are specifically on point.

I have a Powerpoint presentation originally created using an older version of PP for WinXP (v.2003). I had embedded (NOT linked) AVI videos. These videos are no longer available to me (deleted accidentally a number of years ago).

The embedded PP videos work fine on a WinXP machine with PP2003 but not on a Mac with PP2011. I am unable to extract the video by a simple "save as" command to be able to save the video clip to the HDD; my strategy was to do this to then convert the video clip into a more usable format.

Any suggested solutions? Either ripping the video to convert and to embed link or to play the AVI directly in the PP on a Mac machine (runs Maverick)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can open the presentation in a more recent version of Windows PowerPoint  (2007 or later) and save as PPTX, you can rename the file to give it a ZIP extension, open the ZIP then browse to the Media folder within it.  You might find the embedded file there, where you can just drag it out to the desktop or to some other folder.

You might even be able to do this in PPT 2011/Mac, but not sure of that.